# Multidimensional arrays in C# with strings

Tags: c#

I want to do something that resembles a multidimenisional array in C# like it can be done in PHP, for example:

```
$album = array('title' => 'Encore', 'artist' => 'Eminem, 'year' => 2004);
```

How can I do so in C#? Currently I have this code:

```
Album encore = new Album("Encore", "Eminem", 2004);
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: How about `string[,,]` which is a 3dimensional Array, if thats what you want

Comment: You want an array of classes.

Comment: sorry thanks for fast response.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _like it can be done in PHP_?

Comment: your php code shows single dimensional php array, but php's arrays are hashmap (dictionaries) actually, so you're looking for c# syntax for hash maps

Comment: im new to c# didnt know that

Comment: Well, do you have an `Album` class?  The one line of code you have makes plenty of sense, assuming you've built that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, as far as I understand your question.

1.Creating a simple 3d array of strings (not recommended, rather error-prone)

```
public void SetupAlbums()
{
    string[,,] albums = new string[10,10,10];
    albums[0,0,0] = "Encore";
    albums[1,0,0] = "Eminem";
    albums[2,0,0] = "2004";
    // TODO: add more albums here as shown above
}
```

2.Creating a class to hold your data

```
public class Album
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Artist { get; set; }
    string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
List<Album> albums = new List<Album>();
albums.Add(new Album{"Encore", "Eminem", "2004"});
// TODO: add more albums here as shown above
```

I would go for 2. as it is easier to understand, less error-prone and can grow (the array is fixed size of whatever you specifiy, here is specified `10`).

Comment: I dont know what I want to use, I was thinking maybe a sqlite to store my data, cuz im creating an android app where i want the user to write the album information themselves... i dont know if its an irrelevant question but can i use sqlite inside an android app?

Comment: Thanks for making this the accepted answer. Also you can certainly use a SQLite database, and I would recommend storing the data you fetch from the database using option 2.

Comment: I found a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAw0Fa92qNE